# Flyway db migration with sqlite error occurred

Tags: sqlite, flyway

When I use flyway db to migration in my java web app, I got below error.

my code is :

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
flyway.migrate();
```

Does someone know why? Thanks.

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
at org.sqlite.Unused.unused(Unused.java:29) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.Unused.setEscapeProcessing(Unused.java:36) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar:na]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.setEscapeProcessing(NewProxyStatement.java:272) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:235) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:114) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.createIfNotExists(MetaDataTableImpl.java:93) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.lock(MetaDataTableImpl.java:100) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:158) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:156) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]

at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:156) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:972) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:919) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1320) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:919) [flyway-core-3.1.jar:na]
```

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of the driver (3.8.7) and try again

Comment: Looking at the Flyway source this appears to be caused by a call to `Statement.setEscapeProcessing(false)` (see [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/JdbcTemplate.java#L235)) which is not yet implemented in the SQLite driver (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/src/cb3185b148726e00530779014e69d1475697084c/src/main/java/org/sqlite/Stmt.java?at=default#cl-495)). The only solution for me was to downgrade Flyway to 3.0.